# R: Como criar/salvar um vetor usando for e paste?

Tags: r

Gostaria de rodar um `for` e salvar 3 diferentes vetores com por exemplo: `vetor_1`, `vetor_2` e `vetor_3`. Cada vetor está recendo um conjunto diferente de valores. Não consigo fazer esse `paste` ser o nome do vetor, por exemplo, `paste("vetor_",i, sep="")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá pra fazer exatamente o que é pedido usando a função `assign`:

```
for(i in 1:3) { 
  nome <- paste("vetor_", i, sep = "")
  assign(nome, rnorm(10))
}
```

Comment: Buenas Marcus, to desenrolando aqui, já dou um feedback. Tks!

Comment: Todos os exemplos funcionaram bem. Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Em vez de criar 3 (ou mais) vetores no `.GlobalEnv`, a prática recomendada é guardá-los numa lista. Imagine que os valores vêm de uma função, como por exemplo a função `valores`.

```
valores <- function(x, max.length = 10){
  n <- sample(max.length, 1)
  rnorm(n, mean = x)
}
```

Pode criar os vetores de duas maneiras.

**1. `lapply`**

```
set.seed(1234)

lista_vetores <- lapply(1:3, valores)
names(lista_vetores) <- paste0("vetor_", seq_along(lista_vetores))
lista_vetores
#$vetor_1
#[1]  1.6782714  2.0295630 -0.7295285 -1.2043481  1.5431729
#
#$vetor_2
#[1] 0.3709065
#
#$vetor_3
# [1] 4.241754 3.782777 3.048121 1.524600 3.435762 2.929530 3.111197
# [8] 4.273505 2.506616 4.260114
```

Agora qualquer destas maneiras é equivalente.

```
lista_vetores[[1]]
lista_vetores[["vetor_1"]]
lista_vetores$vetor_1
[1]  1.6782714  2.0295630 -0.7295285 -1.2043481  1.5431729
```

**2. ciclo `for`**

```
set.seed(1234)
lista_vetores_2 <- vector("list", 3)
for(i in 1:3){
  lista_vetores_2[[i]] <- valores(i)
}

names(lista_vetores_2) <- paste0("vetor_", seq_along(lista_vetores_2))
identical(lista_vetores, lista_vetores_2)
#[1] TRUE
```